# why GCC Build always have errors like this?

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, gcc-warning

I always have an error when I try to build a source in VScode.
When i first made a code and build, it's no problem but when i change some codes and try to rebuild it the error happens

this it the error message

```
gcc.exe: error: C:Users82103DesktopDsmatrix.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '-c', 'gcc C:\Users\82103\Desktop\Ds\matrix.c -o C:\Users\82103\Desktop\Ds/matrix'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

Comment: It's because the backslashes (`\ `) are interpreted by `bash` as the start of escape sequences. Use forward slashes (`/`) everywhere in your paths and it should work.